# No sound after upgrade to Ubuntu Mate 20.04 LTS from 18.04 LTS ( then worked good)

Tags: upgrade

#Upgrade20.04LTS No sound after upgrade to Ubuntu Mate 20.04 LTS from 18.04 LTS ( then worked good)

When checking preference at Sound, it showed that my hardware was not in use, and not possible to put on. Working on Lenova laptop G580 with 8 Ram.Did updates and re-start. Does say there is an " internal error, did do send report 2 times.

All this with no results.

How to get it working?

How to roll back to 18.04 LTS ?